# Is there a way to rearrange my state so that I can show the image URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface, state

I have a React component (also using TypeScript) that returns a photo to its parent component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const Photo = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState<Image[]>([]);

  // Backend API
  const proxyUrl = "http://localhost:3001";
  const api = "/photo";

  interface Image {
    src: string;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function callAPI() {
      axios
        .get<Image>(proxyUrl + api)
        .then((response) => {
          setImage([
            {
              ...response.data,
            },
          ]);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    })();
  }, []);

  if (image.length === 0) return <span>loading Image...</span>;

  return <img src={String(image[0])} />;
```

The goal is to get an artist's profile picture from my backend. The only way that I can save the image in state is by using the spread operator, and when I do so, it SPREADS the URL - placing each taking each letter and placing it as a value in an object (see the screenshot below).

When I remove the spread operator, I get lots of errors. I need a way to retrieve the photo URL without breaking it up so that I can return and view it. Perhaps by changing the way I defined the interface? Or by setting up state differently?

[Image of the URL being spread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weHUO.png)

Comment: why you want use array for image?

Comment: Ideally I’d simply save in in a string, but since I’m grabbing the image through Axios, the return type is AxiosReponse. Couldn’t figure out how to simplify things.

Comment: can i see your response.data?please add it in your question

Comment: response.data WITHOUT the spread operator is a exactly what I need, it’s the URL for the image - “HTTPS://...” The problem is when I remove the spread operator, everything breaks. I need to be able to save the response.data (a string holding a URL) in state.

Comment: try this :  setImage(response.data) and <img src={image} />

Comment: Tried it, no go, these are the errors:

Argument of type 'Image' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Image[]>'.
  Type 'Image' is not assignable to type '(prevState: Image[]) => Image[]'.
    Type 'Image' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: Image[]): Image[]'.ts(2345)

Comment: you should modify your useState type like this : useState<String>

Comment: I modified it to this: const [image, setImage] = useState<String>();

Still doesn't like it:

Argument of type 'Image' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<String | undefined>'.
  Type 'Image' is not assignable to type '(prevState: String | undefined) => String | undefined'.
    Type 'Image' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: String | undefined): String | undefined'.ts(2345)

Comment: get<Image> ->  get

Comment: Ok, so that actually got rid of the error on response.data.

There's still an error under the 'src' part of return <img src={image} />:

Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object. Prefer using 'string' when possible.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(2074, 9): The expected type comes from property 'src' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>'

Answer (score 0):

first of all modify your useState like this :

```
  const [image, setImage] = useState<String>([]);
```

and data is fetched you should setState like this :

```
setImage(response.data)
```

and delete Image from your get function type.

your return :

```
  return <img src={image)} />;
```

Comment: I just did that, two different issues. The first is with the state modification:
Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'String | (() => String)'.
  Type 'never[]' is missing the following properties from type 'String': charAt, charCodeAt, localeCompare, match, and 36 more.ts(2345)

Second:
Argument of type 'Image' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<String>'.
  Type 'Image' is not assignable to type '(prevState: String) => String'.
    Type 'Image' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: String): String'.ts(2345)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the comments above by mortezashojaei, I was able to tweak the component and finally able to get it to work as intended. Adding the code here in case anyone's interested.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const Photo = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState<string>("");

  // Backend API
  const proxyUrl = "http://localhost:3001";
  const api = "/photo";

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function callAPI() {
      axios
        .get(proxyUrl + api)
        .then((response) => {
          setImage(response.data);
          console.log("RESPONSE.DATA");
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    })();
  }, []);

  console.log("Image (state): ");
  console.log(image);

  if (!image) return <span>loading Image...</span>;

  return <img src={image} />;
};
```